# How to create one launch image for iPhone5, 6, and 6+?

Tags: ios, iphone

Suppose I just want to use one launch image that is sized 1244 x 2208 for iPhone6+, iPhone6, and iPhone5 (they are all proportional), Is there a way to accomplish this? After much trying, I don't believe you can do it with an asset catalog.

Comment: @Fogmeister - I am using an asset catalog.

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close. How can I be more clear in what I'm asking?

Comment: Not my votes. But if you're using the asset catalog then the naming convention is irrelevant. The catalog has slots for each different launch image and even tells you if they're the wrong size etc...

Comment: @Fogmeister - Yeah but can the asset catalog make it so I only have to use one image for the launch screen of iPhone5, iPhone6 and iPhone6+? I don't believe it can.

Comment: No, but then. That isn't possible even without asset catalogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there is no way to do this. You must specify three separate launch images for each screen size in an asset catalog.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode doesn't know what you want it to do with the image... It asks for you to supply the images at the exact resolution because that way it knows exactly how you want the image too look.

If you wanted to use the same image that you made for your iPhone 6+ as the iPhone 6 image, what does Xcode do? Does it scale it down? Does it centre it? You need to either specify different images for each device size yourself (using asset catalogs).

**Or**

You could use a storyboard launch image (introduced in Xcode 6).

Ole Begemann has put together a nice little article here [showing](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/) you how you can achieve this.. You could then add a UIImageView to the storyboard and provide the single image, that way you can specify if you want it to scale to fit or just centre itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I believe the storyboard launch image can only be used for iOS8. How would you do it with an asset catalog? I don't think you can accomplish this with slicing.